# Dropping a group of columns based on a condition fulfilled by a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe whereby the column names are tuples. Below is a sample data for my dataframe:

```
data = {"('7086', 'Open')": {5: 0.0700000002980232, 6: 0.0649999976158142, 7: 0.0750000029802322, 8: 0.0649999976158142, 9: 0.0700000002980232},
 "('7086', 'High')": {5: 0.0700000002980232, 6: 0.0750000029802322, 7: 0.0750000029802322, 8: 0.0750000029802322, 9: 0.0700000002980232},
 "('7086', 'Low')": {5: 0.0700000002980232, 6: 0.0649999976158142, 7: 0.0750000029802322, 8: 0.0649999976158142, 9: 0.0700000002980232},
 "('7086', 'Close')": {5: 0.0700000002980232, 6: 0.0750000029802322, 7: 0.0750000029802322, 8: 0.0750000029802322, 9: 0.0700000002980232},
 "('7086', 'Adj Close')": {5: 0.0700000002980232, 6: 0.0750000029802322, 7: 0.0750000029802322, 8: 0.0750000029802322, 9: 0.0700000002980232},
 "('7086', 'Volume')": {5: 0, 6: 3200, 7: 0, 8: 200800, 9: 260000},
 "('03028', 'Open')": {5: 0.3600000143051147, 6: 0.3600000143051147, 7: 0.3600000143051147, 8: 0.3600000143051147, 9: 0.3600000143051147},
 "('03028', 'High')": {5: 0.3600000143051147, 6: 0.3600000143051147, 7: 0.3600000143051147, 8: 0.3600000143051147, 9: 0.3600000143051147},
 "('03028', 'Low')": {5: 0.3600000143051147, 6: 0.3600000143051147, 7: 0.3600000143051147, 8: 0.3600000143051147, 9: 0.3600000143051147},
 "('03028', 'Close')": {5: 0.3600000143051147, 6: 0.3600000143051147, 7: 0.3600000143051147, 8: 0.3600000143051147, 9: 0.3600000143051147},
 "('03028', 'Adj Close')": {5: 0.3509772419929504, 6: 0.3509772419929504, 7: 0.3509772419929504, 8: 0.3509772419929504, 9: 0.3509772419929504},
 "('03028', 'Volume')": {5: 15500.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   ('7086', 'Open')  ...  ('03028', 'Volume')
5             0.070  ...              15500.0
6             0.065  ...                  0.0
7             0.075  ...                  0.0
8             0.065  ...                  0.0
9             0.070  ...                  0.0

[5 rows x 12 columns]
```

Now, what I hope to perform is to remove the group of columns with the same number code when one of the columns in the number code has only 1 unique number:

```
df.nunique()

('7086', 'Open')          3
('7086', 'High')          2
('7086', 'Low')           3
('7086', 'Close')         2
('7086', 'Adj Close')     2
('7086', 'Volume')        4
('03028', 'Open')         1
('03028', 'High')         1
('03028', 'Low')          1
('03028', 'Close')        1
('03028', 'Adj Close')    1
('03028', 'Volume')       2
dtype: int64
```

As above, we can see in the number code `03028`, that 5 out of 6 columns have only 1 unique value. Therefore, I wish to remove all the 6 columns with the same number code based on this fact. Is there any idea I can do that? I was thinking of grouping it together and dropping it. But I'm not sure how to deal with the tuples. Thanks in advance.

My expected output will be:

```
   ('7086', 'Open')  ...  ('7086', 'Volume')
5             0.070  ...                   0
6             0.065  ...                3200
7             0.075  ...                   0
8             0.065  ...              200800
9             0.070  ...              260000

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: My exact data has 1530 columns, so I get stuck at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```py
import ast

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(ast.literal_eval, df.columns))

filter_ = (df.nunique()==1).groupby(level=0).any()
df.drop(filter_[filter_].index, axis=1, level=0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Epsi95! May I ask what is this `ast` package?

Comment: The ast module helps Python applications to process trees of the Python abstract syntax grammar. The abstract syntax itself might change with each Python release; this module helps to find out programmatically what the current grammar looks like.

Comment: It sounds quite abstract to me, but I will look through this more. Anyway, this answer suits my purpose of grouping it! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
out = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains("'03028',")]
```

If multiple

```
out = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains("'03028',|'00000',")]
```

Comment: Thanks @BENY, this is a really good solution! Just curious if I can improvise it to drop more than 1 number code? As there are 1530 columns in my real dataset.

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew yes you can

Comment: That's great to know, but perhaps if it's not manually added into the code? Just to let you know my situation, I have more than 10 number codes that need to be dropped